# Gaming laptop with NVIDIA graphics fails to boot under any circumstances without a charger

Tags: nvidia, power-management, shutdown, laptop, battery

Awhile ago I installed Arch Linux on my laptop, and while it's been great, there has been one problem: the system will not boot **without being connected to an external power supply**, unless I use heavy power saving techniques, in which case it will be fine for a little while until randomly shutting down. The same happens if I unplug it after booting - it randomly shuts down, happening quicker under load.

This happened in my first installation of Artix Linux, then an installation of Arch, then an installation of Pop!_OS, and then finally my current Arch Linux installation. **It does not happen when I boot to Windows.**

The system in question is an MSI GF65 Thin 9SD, with an Intel i7 9th gen and a NVIDIA GTX 16 series graphics chip.
There is nothing in the logs, either. No complaints of low power or sudden shutdowns.

I would really appreciate some help, I have had this problem for more than a year now.

Edit: The system gets through GRUB just fine, but after "triggering uevents" it usually stops. I updated the BIOS, but still no luck. I tried laptopmodetools, which helped a bit, but it still almost always loses power, I think that this is because laptopmodetools doesn't kick in in time.

Comment: A BIOS upgrade is highly recommended. There is quite a number of issues with NVIDIA and laptops under Linux, e.g. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/has-anyone-been-able-to-run-an-rtx-3060-laptop-gpu-at-more-than-80w-on-linux/192959

Comment: To be honest I smell something fishy here. Can you confirm your laptop works just OK while you're in BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I don't know how to verify that, beyond just being able to boot through GRUB, and I updated the BIOS, so we will see if that helps.

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: How old is the laptop? Is the battery perhaps dying? "Triggering uevents" is probably about the point where the operating system turns on all the devices like the GPU

Comment: @user253751, you are probably right.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED". If you have a solution, consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer